# $f(x)-T_{f,x_0,n}=o(x-x_0)^{n} \implies f(x) \sim T_{f,x_0,n}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm not sure about this.

Consider a function $f$ and it's $n$ degree Taylor Polynomial in $x_0$ $T_{f,x_0,n}$.

Considered the remainder function

$R(x)=f(x)-T_{f,x_0,n}=o(x-x_0)^{n}$

Can I conclude from this that as $x \to x_0$ $f(x) \sim T_{f,x_0,n}$?

As $x \to x_0$ we have

$f(x)-T_{f,x_0,n}=o(x-x_0)^{n} \implies f(x)-T_{f,x_0,n}=o(T_{f,x_0,n}) \implies f(x) \sim T_{f,x_0,n} $

Is this correct?

**Edit**: Considered two functions $f$ and $g$ with "$f\sim g$ as $x\to x_0$" I mean that $lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ or equivalently that $f(x)-g(x)=o(g(x))$

Comment: Could you explain what you think $\sim$ means here? Usually it is used to denote a (n approximately or asymptotically) linear (not affine linear) relation.

Comment: Now if $f(x_0)\ne 0$, then this means that $o(T)=o(1)$ which would render $f\sim T$ at $x_0$ equivalent to $f$ being continuous in $x_0$. Which is rather weak for all this preparation.